# IE8 forces image download on remote server

Tags: php, internet-explorer, image, browser

This link links to an image:
http://pix-all.com/t/w

Every other browser displays this image, only IE forces to download it.
The correct headers are set via PHP.

Is odd though that it works on my local testing server.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Happens on IE 7 as well, not just 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content-type should be "image/jpeg", not "image/jpg".